# Optimize two nested for-loops and if-condition

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization

I have the following piece of code, which runs through two nested `for`-loops and has an `if` condition in the middle:

```
N=1e4;

cond_array = [0:(N/2-1) -N/2+(0:(N/2-1))]/(N);
condition  = 0.1;

arr_one = zeros(N, 1);
arr_two = zeros(N, 1);

for m=1:N
    for k=1:N
        if(abs(cond_array(k)) <= condition)
            arr_one(m)  = arr_one(m)  + m*k;
        else
            arr_two(m)  = arr_two(m)  + m*k;
        end
    end
end
```

I'd like to optimize this code as I potentially need to use very large `N` (`>1e4`) and from my own experience, `for`-loops in MATLAB are often very CPU-consuming and not very efficient.

Is there a way to optimize this piece of code, maybe by using vectorized functions that work on entire arrays?

Comment: `arr_one = (1:N)*sum(find(abs(cond_array) <= condition))` and similarly for `arr_two`?

Comment: Optimization of working code is actually the purpose of [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) so questions like this are very welcomed there! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a much faster (and readable) way to get the same result:

```
N=1e4;
cond_array = [0:(N/2-1) -N/2+(0:(N/2-1))]/(N);
condition  = 0.1;
% this is so you don't check the same condition multiple times:
cond = abs(cond_array)<=condition;
% a vector of the positions in 'arr_one' and 'arr_two':
pos = (1:N).';
% instead of m*k(1)+m*k(2)... use: m*sum(k):
k1 = sum(pos(cond)); % for arr_one
k2 = sum(pos(~cond));% for arr_two
% the final result:
arr_one = pos.*k1;
arr_two = pos.*k2;
```

For the second case you mention in the comments, where `m*k` becomes `exp((m-1)*(k-1))`, we can again compute the sum of `exp((m(1)-1)*(k(1)-1)) +...+ exp((m(1)-1)*(k(N)-1))...` using vectorization, and then use some minimal loop to go over all `m`s:

```
% we define new vectors of constants:
k1 = pos(cond);
k2 = pos(~cond);
% define new functions for each of the arrays:
ek1 = @(m) sum(exp((m-1).*(k1-1)));
ek2 = @(m) sum(exp((m-1).*(k2-1)));
% and we use 'arrayfun' for the final result:
arr_one = arrayfun(ek1,1:N).';
arr_two = arrayfun(ek2,1:N).';
```

`arrayfun` is not faster than a `for` loop, just more compact. Using a `for` loop will be like this:

```
arr_one = zeros(N,1);
arr_two = zeros(N,1);
for k = 1:N
    arr_one(k) = ek1(k);
    arr_two(k) = ek2(k);
end
```

And here is another, more general, option using `bsxfun`:

```
ek = @(m,k) exp((m-1).*(k-1));
arr_one = sum(bsxfun(ek,1:N,k1)).';
arr_two = sum(bsxfun(ek,1:N,k2)).';
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `arr_one(N,1) = 0;` is safe, you may end up having random values in your vector, if I'm not mistaken. Better use `zeros(N, 1)` to be safe.

Comment: @gaborous **It is safe**, MATLAB initiate a zeros matrix anyway, you can check it yourself. Try `arr_one(k)` with any `k` smaller than `N` after this initialization and see if you get something other than zero.

Comment: Well, I [have just seen](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance#comment-359956) that since MATLAB R2015b, the zeros function is faster. So I edit my answer.

Comment: @EBH Thanks. What if the last term `m*k` takes a more advanced form such as `exp((m-1)*(k-1))`?

Comment: @BillyJean this is more nath than programing, and also a subject for another question, but any how, see my edit. And please, if it solved the problem, consider accepting the answer, and if you have further question on specific scenarios - post a new question.

Comment: @EBH, have a look [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120772/discussion-between-stewie-griffin-and-ebh)... I'll give you a 100 rep bounty if you can beat a basic loop with arrayfun in either R2015b and R2016b. :) Please ping me in chat, or with a comment on an answer of mine =) PS! It doesn't have to be **my** loop that beats it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the use of logical indexing. 
Without understanding your code too well, I'd imagine that you can remove the loops through array functions similar to the below.

```
arr_one(abs(cond_array)<condition)
```

This will remove the need for the comparison function, which will allow you to use an anonymous [array function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) in order to create your computation.

However, if I understand your code correctly, you're just adding the product of the position of the condition index and the position of the array index to the array. 
If you do that, it will be much easier to just do something similar to the below.

```
position=(1:N)'
arr_one(abs(cond_array)<condition)=arr_one(abs(cond_array)<condition)+position(abs(cond_array)<condition)
```

In this statement, you're looking for all the items where the cond_array is less than the condition, and adding the position (effectively a proxy for the m and k in your previous example).

In terms of runtime, I think you have to be 1 to 3 orders of magnitude larger than 1e4 for this code to make a significant difference in runtimes.